# Squid "refusing connections" with big ACL

Tags: proxy, squid, access-control-list, filtering

I've successfully set up squid and it's working as is should. I'm using "Squidman" on OS X Server (underlying squid version is 3.1.12). However, I want to use squid to block certain porn sites, so I grabbed the *Pornography*-list from http://www.squidblacklist.org/downloads.html.

This list, however, is quite large (~16MB). I use the list like this:

```
acl pr0n dstdomain "/Users/admin/Library/Preferences/squid-acl/sqbl-org-pr0n.txt"
```

followed by

```
http_access deny pr0n
```

This works as it should with small lists (~ < 1 MB), but if I want to use this list, squid is refusing to accept connections and acts like if the software would not run. If I comment the list out, everything is fine.

So, is there kind of a general limit in list-length or something similar? Is this problem known?

Answer (score -1):

Thats odd, our blacklists work quite well with squid3.x, if you are using an older version of squid, you should upgrade to a modern version. Older versions of squid have severe performance issues with large acl lists.

Squid2.x is outdated crap.

Comment: Since the poster specifically mentioned Squid 3.1.12, this answer doesn't really help much.